# MVC route to a non mvc page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp-classic

I am trying to integrate classic ASP with MVC 5.

How do I route startup page to my old classic ASP login page?
I tried changing it in the web.config but it does not redirect to old page also.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/oldclassicasp/login.asp" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "../oldclassicasp/login.asp",
    defaults: new { controller = "", action = "../oldclassicasp/login.asp", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: anyone has any solution to this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Classic ASP in ASP.NET MVC (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683374/classic-asp-in-asp-net-mvc-c)

Comment: @Lankymart thanks for replying.i just need to set the default landing page to asp only.

Comment: Maybe it's more of a duplicate of this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918065/can-asp-net-mvc-routing-and-a-classic-asp-homepage-vbscript-not-web-forms-pla?rq=1 . It seems to explain what needs to be done before you can set a landing page in web.config

Answer (score 0):

If it were an asp.net webform page then you could use mvc's routing but it won't work with a Classic ASP page.

One hack which occurs to me - you could add a webform page, and then in the codebehind use `Server.TransferRequest("~/path-from-root-to/login.asp");`.

For the record, the syntax if you were setting a webform as the landing page would be as follows

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
            routeName: "Homepage",
            routeUrl: "",
            physicalFile: "~/path-from-root-to/yourwebform.aspx"
        );
```

If you're setting friendly urls for anything other than the landing page then you can use the IIS URL rewrite module